# How can i store file name as a variable in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

what is wrong with following code?

```
TEXT=$(<"$(pwd)/data.csv")
IFS=','
cut -d, -f1,2  $TEXT | while read street city ; do
    echo "$street $city"
done
```

If I am providing the file name directly then it is working

```
IFS=','
cut -d, -f1,2  data.csv | while read street city ; do
    echo "$street $city"
done
```

Comment: You have a < (less than sign) when parameterizing the TEXT variable

Comment: ... which reads the *contents* of the file into `TEXT` instead of its name.

Comment: You set `IFS=,` ... why use `cut`?

Comment: @PaulHodges I am using cut inorder to read only those particular columns from csv file.

Comment: but you are setting IFS and using `read` - you don't need to use `cut`. Just `IFS=',' while read street city x` and ignore `$x`.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i store file name as a variable in shell script

```sh
#!/bin/bash

FILEPATH="$(pwd)/something"
echo $FILEPATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply execute this code:

```
while read street city ; do
  echo "$street $city"
done < data.csv
```

Comment: Delimiter is a comma. Add `IFS="$IFS,"` or just `IFS=,` in front of your `read`.